# Why These Optimization Problems Do Not Align Properly?

Tags: optidef

I'm writing some LaTex notes on optimization using the package `optidef` and I noticed a problem with the 'identation' I'm obtainig. Let me show you two examples. While the code

```
\begin{mini*}
  {}{\langle x,c\rangle}{\label{SOCP}}{}  
  \addConstraint{A(x)}{\succeq_{_{L}}b}
  \addConstraint{x}{\in K.}
   \end{mini*}
```

works perfectly, the following outputs really poor alignment.

```
\begin{mini*}
  {}{-\sum_{j\in [k]}n_j,\log(\beta_j)}{}{}  
  \addConstraint{\sum_{j\in [k]}\beta_j}{=1.}
\end{mini*}
```

However, I'm not able to figure out what exactly is causing such difference. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tweak the alignment with a `\hphantom{-}`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{optidef}

\begin{document}
\begin{mini*}
  {}{\langle x,c\rangle}{\label{SOCP}}{}  
  \addConstraint{A(x)}{\succeq_{_{L}}b}
  \addConstraint{x}{\in K.}
   \end{mini*}
works perfectly, the following now is also aligned.
\begin{mini*}
  {}{{-}\sum_{j\in [k]}n_j,\log(\beta_j)}{}{}  
  \addConstraint{{\hphantom{-}}\sum_{j\in [k]}\beta_j}{=1.}
\end{mini*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm sorry that I can't upvote your answer because I don't have enough reputation yet, but it worked out perfectly! Thank u so much!

Comment: @ArielSerranoni: You should be able to upvote now. However, the alignment still seems slightly off, not sure why.  For future reference, while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it

Comment: Sorry, but 15 points are needed to upvote. Thanks for the reference, I noticed that I could have done better including the compilation in my question but didn't know how to do it.